# Electric field inside sphere - Griffiths Problem 2.14

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, electric-fields, gauss-law

I've been trying to solve the following problem from Griffiths' *Introduction to Electrodynamics*:

> **Problem 2.14.** Find the electric field inside a sphere that carries a charge density proportional to the distance from the origin, $\rho=kr$, for some constant $k$. [*Hint*: This charge density is *not* uniform, and you must *integrate* to get the enclosed charge.]

The formula given for the electric field from a continuous charge distribution is

$$\vec{E}=\frac{1}{4\pi \varepsilon_0} \iiint \frac{\rho}{r^2}\hat{r}dV$$

In spherical coordinates, $dV=r^2 \sin \theta dr d\theta d\phi$, so the integral becomes

$$E=\frac{1}{4\pi\varepsilon_0}\iiint \rho \sin \theta dr d\theta d\phi=\frac{1}{4\pi\varepsilon_0}\iiint kr \sin \theta drd\theta d\phi$$

If I perform the integration with $r$ ranging from $0$ to some radial distance $x$, I find

$$E=\frac{k}{4\pi \varepsilon_0}\int_0^{2\pi} d\phi \int_0^\pi \sin \theta d\theta \int_0^x r dr=\frac{k}{2\varepsilon_0}x^2$$

However, the answer given is a factor of $2$ smaller: $E=\frac{k}{4\varepsilon_0} x^2$. I cannot account for this difference. I'm not sure why; my integration seems to be fine and I've confirmed it with multiple calculators. Is there something I'm missing? Does the formula I gave not apply in this instance?

Comment: @JimmyYang I understand this can be done using Gauss' law; I'm just wondering why this method doesn't seem to provide the right answer here.

Comment: I’ve hidden a number of comments that should have been posted as answers, and replies to them. To answer a closed question, first vote to reopen.

Answer (score 3):

> The formula given for the electric field from a continuous charge distribution is

> $$\vec{E}=\frac{1}{4\pi \varepsilon_0} \iiint \frac{\rho}{r^2}\hat{r}dV$$

No. This is wrong. Griffiths uses a "**script** r" to represent $\vec r - \vec r'$. But you are just using a single $\vec r$, which is not correct unless you want the field only at the origin.

The correct formula is:
$$
\vec{E}(\vec r)=\frac{1}{4\pi \varepsilon_0} \iiint \frac{\rho(\vec r')(\vec r-\vec r')}{|\vec r - \vec r'|^3}dV'
$$

You can either use the correct formula, or you can use the fact that the distribution is spherically symmetric and you have Gauss's law to figuire out that
$$
E(\vec r) = \frac{Q_{enc}(r)\hat r}{r^2}\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\;,
$$
where $Q_{enc}(r)$ depends on $r$ because the amount of enclosed charge depends on the distance from the origin (since we are *inside* the sphere).